# JQuery Accordion Button - remove flicker on page refresh

Tags: jquery

I have a simple JQuery Accordion menu with Section names in my 'accordionButton' div and navigation links in my 'accordionContent' div. The navigation links each append a new `?page_id=n` to the URL.

The problem is that when a user clicks to a new link within my menu, the whole accordionContent section slides up and then back down. Switching between sections (clicking the accordionButton) does not cause this to happen.

How do I fix this? Code here:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('div.accordionButton.selected').next().show();

         //ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION  
         $('div.accordionButton').click(function() {

         $('div.accordionContent').slideUp('normal');   
         $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
         $('div.accordionButton').removeClass('selected');
         $(this).addClass('selected');  
         });
     });
```

Comment: Are the links that trigger the menu close event taking the user to new pages or just sections of the same page?

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle?

Comment: It's technically the same page, but all of the content reloads and server-side processing happens.

Answer (score 0):

i did an accordion with more solid way, and wont broke with urls. you should try this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5QY4g/5/)**